# JavaScript regex string translation and reordering

Tags: javascript, regex

I need the following strings:

```
1st Set Risultato Esatto
2nd Set Risultato Esatto
3rd Set Risultato Esatto
4th Set Risultato Esatto
5th Set Risultato Esatto
```

Turning into:

```
Punteggio 1° Set
Punteggio 2° Set
Punteggio 3° Set
Punteggio 4° Set
Punteggio 5° Set
```

Preferably using regex. I have done the following for my first solution:

```
  const regex = /Set ([0-9.]+) Total Games Over\/Under ([0-30.]+)/;
  let match;
  let browserReturn;
  if(marketLabel.includes('Set' && 'Total Games Over/Under')) {
    match = regex.exec(marketLabel);
    browserReturn = 'Under/Over ' + match[2] + ' Giochi Set ' + match[1];
    return browserReturn;
  }
```

Comment: Are those 5 separate strings, or is that a single, multi-line string?

Comment: Your regular expressions have *nothing* to do with your input strings. That's confusing. Please try to write self-contained questions that do not require any cross-reading to understand them.

Comment: As mentioned, I have done this regular expression for some other strings, the code above is an example from another regex.

Comment: They are indeed multi-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention the numbers are only ever going to be between `1` and `5`, we can make this rather simple:

```js
var strings = ["1st Set Risultato Esatto", "2nd Set Risultato Esatto", "3rd Set Risultato Esatto", "4th Set Risultato Esatto", "5th Set Risultato Esatto"];

for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
  console.log("Punteggio " + strings[i][0] + "° Set");
}
```

You only need to get the first character from each string (`strings[i][0]`), and place that into the result string.

Another option:

```js
var strings = ["1st Set Risultato Esatto", "2nd Set Risultato Esatto", "3rd Set Risultato Esatto", "4th Set Risultato Esatto", "5th Set Risultato Esatto"];
var result = strings.map(function(str){
    return "Punteggio " + str[0] + "° Set";
});
console.log(result);
```

---

In case the strings aren't separated yet, you're going to have to split them, first:

```js
var str = `1st Set Risultato Esatto
2nd Set Risultato Esatto
3rd Set Risultato Esatto
4th Set Risultato Esatto
5th Set Risultato Esatto`;

var strings = str.split(/[\r\n]+/);

console.log(strings);
```

Comment: Yes your answer also work, but there is actually no point of having this question here... if all op needs to get the first digit out of the sentence and form a sentence. The question which should come to a developer's mind is, do the rest of the words fits the format or not. if yes, then pick the digit.

Comment: @Maverick_Mrt: _"Cheking the rest of the string"_ isn't part of the question. The OP just wants to transform one string into something else. And that's what this answer does, right?

Comment: yes i said, it does... your answer would even pick the first letter even if it is not a digit.... what you did is what he wants... then that is a "no question"

Comment: infact, op's provided regex snippet says that, it matches the rest of the string if that fits or not

Answer (score 0):

If you have only that number in your strings, you can use this replace:

```
replace(/(\d)(.+)/g, "Punteggio $1º Set")
```

```js
var strings = [
  "1st Set Risultato Esatto",
  "2nd Set Risultato Esatto",
  "3rd Set Risultato Esatto",
  "4th Set Risultato Esatto",
  "5th Set Risultato Esatto"
];

strings.forEach(x => console.log(x.replace(/(\d+).+/g, "Punteggio $1º Set")));
```

It only works with that specific string where it start with the number:

```
(\d+) - Takes the number from the beggining into the first block($1)
```

Comment: How about `/(\d+).+/g`? No need to capture that 2nd group.